# htaccess regex with two periods in file name

Tags: regex, .htaccess

I have this current expression, that takes `site.com/index.php` to `site.com/index`

```
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

I need to make it accept filename with two periods in them, like `site.com/core.index.php` to `site.com/core.index`

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Try `RewriteRule ^(.+)(\.[^\.]+)?$ $1.php [NC,L]`

Comment: I guess `index.php` should not be redirected to `index.php.php`?

Comment: To avoid this we should use !-f instead of !-d

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More simple solution also available:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f   # We don`t have such file (includes !-d)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC,L]     # Just add .php to the end
```

Answer (score 1):

The regex `^(.*)(?<!\.php)$` matches every address not ending with ".php", so

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)(?<!\.php)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

could work. I am not that familiar with RewriteRule, though.

Answer (score 0):

Use this regex `^[\w\d]*\.[\w\d]*\/[\w\d]*\.[\w\d]*`
[image]

Comment: This solution is less useful than 1st and 3rd. It`s like something hardcoded and not always will capture all possible options.