# htaccess breaks indexs

Tags: regex, .htaccess

This works perfect: `^(.*)$` (lets `site.com/login.php` work like `site.com/login`) except it breaks all indexes. I can't get any index file to show up, even index set by the same `.htaccess` file. It just shows a blank page until I remove this `^(.*)$`. Any thoughts?

Rrelated question: [htaccess regex with two periods in file name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5945975/htaccess-regex-with-two-periods-in-file-name)

Answer (score 0):

`^(.*)$` matches anything, even nothing. Force it to require at least one character instead.

```
^(.+)$
```